# Check If Remote File Exists

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net (using vs2005), I'd like to see if www.domain.com/myfile.txt exists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can browse to this file, you could use the [HTTPWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and either grab the file and check it or get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access an internet URL is via the [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) class.